# ASP.net treeview. How to change rendering from table to list

Tags: asp.net, treeview

I have a Treeview control which is currently outputting the results in an HTML table element, Ideally I would like to get this to output as an unordered List.

Something like 
       <asp:TreeView RenderAsList="True">
would be great if possible. Of course if it were that easy I wouldn't be here!

Thanks in advance

Comment: I forgot to mention that I have no access to the code behind, I can only affect the ASPX

Comment: You could probably use javascipt to manipulate the DOM (jQuery is great for this) to turn your `<table>` *into* a `<ul>`.  Sounds like it might be kind of a brittle solution though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're wanting to make this an unordered list, I don't think you'll be able to do that using the normal Treeview control, what you could do is use a Repeater control that will let you build your list in html, and then use some jquery to format that list as a treeview.

http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-treeview/

if you "must" have the full asp:Treeview functionality there is an ancient library that hasn't been updated since 2006 that lets you render output of asp.net controls in a more css/html friendly fashion.

http://www.asp.net/cssadapters/

Comment: Sadly it is a case of having to have the full Treeview. Thanks for the link it gives me something to investigate.